# FreeBSD Bash awk $11 to end of line adding \ before spaces?

Tags: bash, awk, rsync, freebsd, chown

I have been hitting my head against the wall trying to get this to work.

I am writing an rsync backup script for use on freebsd. I do not have root privileges on the remote server, and I need to mv and cp the files well on the remote server so once I restore them I lose ownership.

I am trying to create an permissions file to backup all permissions and ownerships to re apply once a data restore is done.

this is the backup code

```
find /dir -ls >> output_file
```

this is the restore code

```
for f in `cat output_file|awk '{print $11}'` ; do chown `cat output_file|grep $f\$|awk '{print $5 ":" $6}'` $f ; done
```

this is an example of output_file

```
 23319     3857 -rwxrwxrwx    1 root                         root                          1867545 Jan  9 22:55 /mnt/Tank2/Users/root/stampede/Little_House.jpg
 23320     3089 -rwxrwxrwx    1 root                         root                          1530449 Jan  9 22:57 /mnt/Tank2/Users/root/stampede/Milky_Way.jpg
 23325     3857 -rwxrwxrwx    1 root                         root                          1938544 Jan  9 22:47 /mnt/Tank2/Users/root/stampede/Shy_Horses.jpg
 23324     3857 -rwxrwxrwx    1 root                         root                          1940621 Jan  9 22:50 /mnt/Tank2/Users/root/stampede/Reinforcements.jpg
```

everything works great unless there is a space in a file or folder name then it fails.
if my folder is called "folder 1" the script only gets "folder"
I think all I need to do is have "cat output_file|awk '{print $11}'" extend from $11 to the end of the line and before every space to add a \ so the output conforms to standard *nux file format but I am unable to figure out how to do it.

any help would be great!

Comment: Try `cut -d" " --complement -f1` instead `awk ` or you can use `awk '{$11=""; sub(/^ */, "");}1' `

Comment: it outputs ./Backup.sh: line 43: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
./Backup.sh: line 43: ` for f in `cat output_file|awk '{$11=""; sub(/^ */, "");}1' ; do chown `cat output_file|grep $f\$|awk '{print $5 ":" $6}'` $f ; done'

Comment: no error for me can show script?

Comment: for f in `cat output_file|awk '{$11=""; sub(/^ */, "");}1' ; do chown `cat output_file|grep $f\$|awk '{print $5 ":" $6}'` $f ; done

Comment: please paste code in your question window so it looks in proper format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working way too hard, and making the computer work too hard as well.  *Never* pipe cat to grep to awk.  In this case, you don't need any of those tools; just do:

```
while read inode blocks perm links owner group bytes month day time path; do 
    chown $owner:$group "$path"
done < output_file
```

read will put all of the trailing fields into path, preserving white space.

Comment: YES! thats amazing! I was just trying to do it with the tools I know. not that i need to but trying to understand your solution for future reference could this be used to restore permissions? chmod $perm $path ?

Comment: You read the value of the variables from the file; once you have the variables defined, you can do anything you want with them.

Answer (score 0):

### First, check if the output is fine or not.

```
awk '{print $5 ":" $6,substr($0,112)}' output_file
```

if fine, try below script

```
awk '{print $5 ":" $6,substr($0,112)}' output_file |while read perm file
do
  chown "$perm" "$file"
done
```

Comment: output becomes: chown: 12 22:36 /mnt/Tank2/Users/root/week 1: No such file or directory

Comment: Please run the awk command manually first, you may need adjust the number in substr() , in my system, it is 78, but from your output_file , it is 112. You need confirm by yourself.

Comment: changing 110 in the awk command changes the number of spaces but it always displays the data after the spaces however. i tried several different numbers with the final script and non make a differance same output as i posted every time

Comment: I see. The error is on $5 and $6, seems they are not owner and group. (12 22:36, date and time ??), can you adjust it as well?